# Como leer un archivo .txt y asignar el valor leído a un arreglo estructurado?

Tags: c, archivo, float, struct

tengo un problema al leer valores de un archivo .txt y asignar estos valores a un arreglo dinámico de tipo estructurado.
El problema es que el programa si puede leer y asignar los valores en la primera posición del arreglo, pero cuando intento que lea y asigne los valores leídos a las siguientes posiciones del arreglo, la ejecución del programa termina.

Estos son los valores que deseo leer y asignar:

```
1|-71.9000|-28.2000|77.2324|201.4157|
2|145.1000|-29.2000|148.0090|348.6217|
3|23.4000|-32.3000|39.8855|305.9218|
4|-39.4000|-64.5000|75.5818|238.5812|
5|13.1000|-56.3000|57.8040|283.0986|
```

Este es el codigo que hice para leer los valores y asignarlos:

```
archivo_puntos=fopen("compendioDePuntos.txt","r"); //Se abre el archivo en donde estan guardados los puntos

    while(!feof(archivo_puntos)){
        fgets(auxiliar, 50, archivo_puntos);
        contador_saltos++;
    }
    contador_saltos=contador_saltos+1;//se cuentan los saltos de linea para determinar cuanto espacio se necesitara en memoria para almacenar las variables

    vaciar(&auxiliar[0]);
    rewind(archivo_puntos);
    
    puntos=(struct punto *)realloc(puntos,(contador_saltos)*sizeof(struct punto)); //Se genera el arreglo de memoria dinamica requerido
    contador_for2=0;
    // while(contador_for2<contador_saltos){
        
        contador_for=0;
        while((caracter=fgetc(archivo_puntos))!='|'){ //Se lee caracter a carácter hasta que se encuentre el caracter '|' y se asigna los caracteres anteriores a la cadena
            if(caracter=='\n'){ //Cada que se encuentra un salto de linea se asigna un valor nulo en la siguiente posicion
                caracter='\0';
                auxiliar[contador_for+1]=caracter;
            }
            auxiliar[contador_for]=caracter;
            contador_for++;
        }
                                                                    //Se van guardando cada caracter del archivo en el arreglo auxiliar para posteriormente transformarlo en entero con la funcion atoi
        puntos[contador_for2].identificador_de_punto=atoi(auxiliar);//se asigna el valor al lugar correspondiente en el arreglo estructurado
        
        vaciar(&auxiliar[0]); //Se vacia el arreglo auxiliar con ayuda de una funcion para evitar errores en los caracteres

        contador_for=0;
        while((caracter=fgetc(archivo_puntos))!='|'){
            if(caracter=='\n'){
            caracter='\0';
            auxiliar[contador_for+1]=caracter;
            }
            auxiliar[contador_for]=caracter;
            contador_for++;
        }
        
        puntos[contador_for2].valor_en_x=atof(auxiliar);
        vaciar(&auxiliar[0]);

        contador_for=0;
        while((caracter=fgetc(archivo_puntos))!='|'){
            if(caracter=='\n'){
            caracter='\0';
            auxiliar[contador_for+1]=caracter;
            }
            auxiliar[contador_for]=caracter;
            contador_for++;
        }
        
        puntos[contador_for2].valor_en_y=atof(auxiliar);
        vaciar(&auxiliar[0]);

        contador_for=0;
        while((caracter=fgetc(archivo_puntos))!='|'){
            if(caracter=='\n'){
            caracter='\0';
            auxiliar[contador_for+1]=caracter;
            }
            auxiliar[contador_for]=caracter;
            contador_for++;
        }
        
        puntos[contador_for2].modulo=atof(auxiliar);
        vaciar(&auxiliar[0]);

        contador_for=0;
        while((caracter=fgetc(archivo_puntos))!='|'){
            if(caracter=='\n'){
            caracter='\0';
            auxiliar[contador_for+1]=caracter;
            }
            auxiliar[contador_for]=caracter;
            contador_for++;
        }
        
        puntos[contador_for2].angulo=atof(auxiliar);
        vaciar(&auxiliar[0]);
        contador_for2++;

    // }
    
    fclose(archivo_puntos);
    printf("\nSe obtuvieron los datos del archivo correctamente\n");
```

Este es el resultado con este código:

```
ID   Cord X    Cord Y   Modulo    Angulo
1  -71.9000  -28.2000  77.2324  201.4157
```

El problema es que solo lee la primera linea del archivo y cuando intente poner el while comentado para intentar que se lean las siguientes lineas el programa se detiene, tambien intente con un ciclo for y pasa lo mismo. Entonces mi pregunta es como puedo leer las siguientes lineas sin que se detenga el programa. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que más te puede servir en tu caso, es una **lista enlazada**, te dejo una implementación corta pero sin "leaks", espero que te sirva:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct s_punto * punto;

struct s_punto
{
    int identificador_de_punto;
    float valor_en_x;
    float valor_en_y;
    float modulo;
    float angulo;
    punto next;
};

// Libera correctamente la lista
punto free_list(punto puntos)
{
    punto aux_p = NULL;
    while (puntos != NULL)
    {
        aux_p = puntos;
        puntos = puntos->next;
        free(aux_p);
        aux_p = NULL;
    }
    return puntos;
}

// Añadir un elemento a la lista
punto addl (punto p, int id, float x, float y, float mod, float ang)
{
    punto new_p = NULL;
    new_p = (punto)malloc(sizeof(struct s_punto));
    new_p->identificador_de_punto = id;
    new_p->valor_en_x = x;
    new_p->valor_en_y = y;
    new_p->modulo = mod;
    new_p->angulo = ang;
    new_p->next = p;
    p = new_p;
    return p;
}

unsigned int length(punto l)
{
    punto mov = NULL;
    mov = l;
    unsigned int count = 0u;
    while(mov != NULL)
    {
        mov = mov->next;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    FILE * input_file = NULL;

    // Abrimos el archivo en modo lectura
    input_file = fopen("foo.txt","rt");
    
    // Ultimo elemento de la lista VACIO
    punto puntos = NULL;

    // Variables auxiliares para cargar la lista
    int id_aux = 0;
    float x_aux = 0;
    float y_aux = 0;
    float mod_aux = 0;
    float ang_aux = 0;
    int last_id = 0;

    // Leyendo el archivo
    while(!feof(input_file))
    {
        fscanf(input_file, "%d|%f|%f|%f|%f|", &id_aux, &x_aux, &y_aux, &mod_aux, &ang_aux);
        if (last_id != id_aux)
        {
            puntos = addl(puntos, id_aux, x_aux, y_aux, mod_aux, ang_aux);
            // Aca va el formato de salida -> yo le mande uno feo
            printf("id -> %d\nx -> %f\ny -> %f\nmodulo -> %f\nangulo -> %f\n", id_aux, x_aux, y_aux, mod_aux, ang_aux);
        }
        // Tomo el salto de linea
        getc(input_file);
        last_id++;
    }
    fclose(input_file);
    puntos = free_list(puntos);
    free(puntos);

    // Evitar "Dangling pointers"
    puntos = NULL;
}
```

PD: Me faltaron verificaciónes, del estilo:

- Revisar si tenemos memoria disponible para llevar a cabo la asignación
- Revisar si se abrió el archivo

Tenelas en cuenta cuando lleves a cabo el desarrollo.